# Saving macro as addin in PowerPoint 2007

Tags: vba, add-in, powerpoint, powerpoint-2007

I've got a question concerning addins in PowerPoint 2007.

It is possible to save a macro as an addin and then use it as a button in all PP presentations? I know it's possible in Excel..but how about PowerPoint?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The presentation should include any macros you want to make available and also some code to create any needed buttons/toolbars to invoke the macros.  Usually this will go in an Auto_Open subroutine (which will fire automatically whenever the add-in loads).

This page on my PPT FAQ site explains how to do this in a way that's compatible with all current versions of PPT/Windows:

[Create an ADD-IN with TOOLBARS that run macros](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00031_Create_an_ADD-IN_with_TOOLBARS_that_run_macros.htm)

It'll create toolbars/buttons that appear on an Add-ins tab in PPT 2007 and up.
If you want to create buttons on the PPT ribbon, it gets a bit more complicated.

Comment: Steve, you should add a summary of that page into this answer. Otherwise, anyone visiting this page has to go to your site to view the instructions, and answers that depend on external links are frowned upon here.

Comment: JimmyPena, I maintain the PowerPoint FAQ so I don't have to reinvent the wheel/rewrite the same answers over and over (no doubt leaving out important bits each time I do). And so that if someone finds the link in an older answer, they'll be directed to content that I update as needed, not old out-of-date information. And because I don't have time to do what you're asking. As you can see, haver24 got an answer that works. I'd say that's something not to be frowned upon. Better an answer in a link than none at all.